# ListBox ItemContainerGenerator returns null even when listbox has items

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, itemcontainergenerator

I've a listbox with couple of items, till the time no scrollbar appears everything goes perfectly fine but once scrollbar comes then ItemContainerGenerator returns null.

I read some blogs and found it may be because of vertualization stackpanel. If i disable that then it may work but in my case it would make listbox too much heavy and less efficient.

Here is the code for listbox:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="EventListBox"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          Margin="5,5,5,5"
          FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding EventModelViewCollectionView}"
          Style="{StaticResource DefaultListBoxStyle}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventTemplate}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding EventModelViewCollection.SelectedItem}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
          ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="EventScrollViewer_ScrollChanged"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          Loaded="ListBox_Unloaded">
```

This returns null.

Here firstContainer should be the first listbox element. I verified that itemsControl is correct and it has items when firstContainer is null.

```
DependencyObject firstContainer = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
```

One more quite noticing thing: 
I saw there're 8 listbox items in ItemsControl. ItemContainerGenerator status says **Container Generated **

No idea why it's not returning ItemsContainer
Thoughts ??

Comment: I've gone through the following link : http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtualization means that listboxitems only gets generated if visible. So you can not use the ItemContainerGenerator to get non generated (non visible) listbox items.

Do you really need the listbox item directly? It looks like your listbox is data driven so work with the data directly.

Comment: I was just going to put an answer the same thing you said. :) ..

Well i actually need the item for providing Custom Drag~Drop support.

Comment: Although i'm able to fix the above problem but got struck in one more issue. In case virtualization is true, ScrollViewer - ViewPortHeight comes to 4.0 (However listbox's actual width is too much greater than this). Is there any work around for this ????

Comment: Are you saying you want to know the total height of all listbox items? If the list box is virtualized then you will not know since non visible items are not generated. If all items have the same height then you can just get height for 1 item * number of items.

Comment: Actually i need type of ListBoxItemContainer. earlier i tried getting first item i.e. ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) but as first element is not generated (bcz of virtualization) it was null. How can i excess the element which is currently displayed. 
Although i'm able to do this by type casting ItemsContainer to listbox and then ContainerFromIndex(listbox's selectedIndex - 1); .. 
It works but i need a generic approach as ItemsControl doesn't have selectedIndex.