# ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem returns null for last few items

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In the code below, in `ColumnsListBox_Loaded` event, this method returns null for last few ListBox items. Any idea why is it happening ?  I am data binding the listbox in OnOpned() event of ChildWindow class and then retrieving these items in Loaded() event of ListBox class.

```
  public partial class SPListColumns : ChildWindow
    {
        Web site;
        List spList;
        ListItemCollection listItems;
        string listName;
        public DataGrid MainGrid;

        public SPListColumns(string listName, DataGrid MainGrid)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listName))
            {
                this.listName = listName;

            }

            this.MainGrid = MainGrid;
        }

        void ColumnsListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataGridTextColumn columnValue in ColumnsListBox.Items)
            {

                ListBoxItem li = ColumnsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(columnValue) as ListBoxItem;
                if (li != null)
                {

                    if (MainGrid.Columns.First(s => s.Header == columnValue.Header).Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
                    {
                        li.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        li.IsSelected = true;
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        protected override void OnOpened()
        {
            base.OnOpened();
            ColumnsListBox.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ColumnsListBox_Loaded);
            BindColumns(listName);
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = true;



            foreach (DataGridTextColumn columnValue in ColumnsListBox.Items)
            {

                ListBoxItem li = ColumnsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(columnValue) as ListBoxItem;
                if (li != null)
                {
                    if (!li.IsSelected)
                    {
                        MainGrid.Columns.First(s => s.Header == columnValue.Header).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BindColumns(string listName)
        {

               ColumnsListBox.Items.Clear();
               ColumnsListBox.ItemsSource = MainGrid.Columns;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListBox may be using virtualization to avoid generating containers for items that are not displayed (which would be why the first items work fine for you).

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729079/listbox-itemcontainergenerator-returns-null-even-when-listbox-has-items) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675926/listview-itemcontainergenerator-containerfromitemitem-return-null-after-20-ite).

You might want to only look at containers for items that are visible; or inherit `ListBox`to override `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` to access the container as it's (re)used if you want to do something on the fly; or turn off virtualization (change the `ItemsPanel` to a `StackPanel` rather than `VirtualizingStackPanel`).